# Where can I find statistics on Soviet education of foreign students and in foreign countries?

Tags: soviet-union, international-relations, education, statistics

I'm looking for statistics on soviet education of the foreign students and in foreign countries. In particular, I am trying to find numbers on:

1. How many foreigners were educated in Soviet Union (e.g. exchange opportunities in [Patrice Lumumba Peoples’ Friendship University of Russia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patrice_Lumumba_Peoples%27_Friendship_University_of_Russia))
2. How many Soviet teachers were sent abroad (e.g. Soviet teachers in African countries)
3. related to the amounts of printed educational products, which were sent to the allies to help them to improve educational system

I will appreciate any possible help in search of related sources.

Comment: [Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s)](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/785/26786).  [Cambridge.ortg](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-global-history/article/lumumba-university-in-moscow-higher-education-for-a-sovietthird-world-alliance-196091/8720DF55AA0CEBC782EC8B215AC08D47) provides _some_ numbers. I can't believe that [PLPFUR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patrice_Lumumba_Peoples%27_Friendship_University_of_Russia) doesn't have this information - have you checked there?